# jest mock ignores implementation when called inside test -- am i doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I have a simple test case at this GitHub repository

https://github.com/paulhoule/demolition_man

which is based on this example from the jest documentation

https://jestjs.io/docs/27.x/mock-functions

with the small modifications that (1) I inlined a function,  (2) I added an expectation (the first) one that confirms the wrong behavior.

The wrong behavior,  as I see it,  is that jest is ignoring the implementation I gave for the mock function.   I've found that (1) the mock function works as as expected *outside the test* and (2) it always returns undefined *inside the test*.  I've seen various answers on this site that suggest I could put something in a beforeEach() that would reset the mocks but none of these made a difference.  The mock works *inside the test* if I define it *inside the test* but if I define it *outside the test* it just ignores the declaration.

I guess I can make all my mocks inside the test but boy that could get verbose.  Note this project was made with create-react-app 5.0.1,  my hunch is that this problem might have to do with webpack or babel.